# Rails performance analyzers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance, plugins

What are the preffered plugins for monitoring and analyzing the performance of a Rails app? I'm looking for both database/query analyzers and the rest of the stack if possible, though not necessarily all in one plugin. Which ones do you recommend?
( Bonus points for free ones :)

For example, [this one](http://railstips.org/2008/9/17/rails-app-monitoring) looks spify.

Answer (score 2):

[RAWK](http://ckhsponge.wordpress.com/2006/10/11/ruby-on-rails-log-analyzer-rawk/) I have used to get performance reports emailed to me at regular intervals. It works by analyzing the rails production logs and has always done well for me.

I recently learned about [Scout](http://scoutapp.com/) from their article about [rails monitoring](http://blog.scoutapp.com/articles/2008/09/09/rails-monitoring-pillars), but I haven't had a chance to try it out yet, looks promising!

Answer (score 2):

+1 for new relic.

Also consider five runs, I haven't played with it, but it appears to have a loopback mode for development mode, vs's new relics production mode

Answer (score 1):

Derek here from [Scout](http://scoutapp.com) - we've added deep Rails instrumentation as a plugin. This means you'll get a breakdown of where the request time is spent (db,rendering,other) as well as optimization suggestions for slow MySQL queries.

You can play with the instrumentation on our [free plan](http://scoutapp.com/signup)

Screenshot: http://img.skitch.com/20090513-fe4mnaqn5e7i3nsde5qdwrr6k5.png

Answer (score 0):

This gives info on query analyzers in Rails

http://ronnyml.wordpress.com/2008/07/03/query-analyzer-for-rails/

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/igorkasyanchuk/rails_performance

I've an own option to monitor performance, it's using Redis to store requests information and not sending data to 3rd party services.

Nothing special, but a simple tool to get the most important reports (rendering time, DB queries, most popular controller#actions)